# How to store the id coming from api and store that in local variable and again assign that Id to the existing variable and post to the api inangular13

Tags: angular

Random Id:any;

Getdata(){

this.serv.getdata(url).subscribe(data=> this.RandomId=data)
}

```
enter code here
```

Comment: And how to post that data to that id again?

Comment: And how to post the existing data object in ts file to that id.Any help is appreciated

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.